# How to make this list of images responsive (scalable)?

Tags: html, css

I just implemented a star rating system on my site, but I'm having a hard time making the images scale alongside my other content. The HTML code I'm using is:

```
<ul id="aff_rating">
    <li><img src="/images/star_on.png" class="star_on starrating-1"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/star_on.png" class="star_on starrating-2"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/star_on.png" class="star_on starrating-3"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/star_on.png" class="star_on starrating-4"></li>
    <li><img src="/images/star_off.png" class="star_off starrating-5"></li>
</ul>
```

I need the stars to scale down as a user resizes their browser window just like the other images on the page.

Comment: I really don't see why you need to scale down things. but I'm pretty sure you'll need javascript here.

Comment: How are the other images on the page resized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a percentage width to your images and `<li>` container so they can scale accordingly along with their parent container, or you can set a different size using `@media` queries.

Here are two methods you can try:

Percentage based:

```
#aff_rating li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:6px;
    width:18%;
}

#aff_rating li img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69KgC/)

`@media` queries based:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    #aff_rating li {
        width:30px; /* define a proper width that you think is right */
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69KgC/1/) (resize result window to test)

Comment: Derp, thanks! I actually was doing it the correct way but an uncleared float was causing it to behave in mysterious and annoying ways.